# My question is can we avoid the if conditions?

Tags: c++, if-statement, embedded, binary-operators

I have a code condition such as following

```
for(int i=0;i<Number;i++)
{     
     int* pIn = pInputArr[i];
     int* pOut = pOutputArr[i];
      
     for(int Input_number =0;Input_number<100;Input_number++)
         {
            Some_fun(pIn,pOut );
            if (Input_number % 2 == 0)
            {
               pIn = pOutputArr[i];
               pOut = pInputArr[i];
            }
            else
           {
               pOut =  pOutputArr[i];
               pIn = pInputArr[i];
           }
      }
 }
```

I wanted to replace it with a more efficient way in embedded programming since I was told that branch operations are costly in embedded programming. Is there a cleaner way to achieve this using bit operations and without the if conditions?.
Also without using any built-in functions such as `swap` and others.

Based on the odd and even condition I am swapping the role of the buffers that are being as arguments in the `Some_func`. I checked similar queries in several posts but didn't find them useful. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It all depends on what "do some operation" does. You can't avoid branching by optimizing the condition.

Comment: My question is can we avoid the if conditions?. Though your point is also valid.

Comment: Again, it depends on your "operation".

Comment: if you need to branch then you need to branch. Suppose `//do some operation` is either `x += 1` or `x += 2` then you don't need a branch.

Comment: Short answer: No.  At least, if `input_number` has a run time value.

Comment: Depends on your processor.  Your processor will need to perform a comparison.  Some processors have conditional instructions that are only executed if the comparison state matches the one in the instruction.  Otherwise, traditionally a branch is used to act upon the comparison.

Comment: You may be able to avoid branches by using algebra or Boolean arithmetic.  Try simplifying expressions.

Comment: I remeber similar issue being discussed and I remember same code, not sure if it was the same ;). `Input_number` does not change in the loop, either the compiler can spot that or branch prediction kicks in, in either case I am afraid you are trying to optimize the wrong line of code

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Don't know about that. But thanks for pointing that

Comment: actually I remembered wrong, the question about an if check of a constant condition inside a loop that I refered to is this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66064292/4117728, semi related

Comment: @churill Have updated the code.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Thanks but that is something else though :)

Comment: unless I'm missing something, both branches still do the same operation.

Comment: the other question is something different because now your code is different, its still not demonstrating the issue that you want to fix, because in the code you posted you can simply remove the if altogether

Comment: Now you don't need a branch or a test at all.  Just use `std::swap(pIn, pOut)` at the end of the nested loop to swap them each iteration.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I felt there was a much-needed more explanation of the question :). Hope the query is understood now?

Comment: Why can't you use `std::swap`?  It's trivial to write your own.  Its just `template <typename T> void swap(T & lhs, T & rhs) { T temp{std::move(lhs)}; lhs = std::move(rhs); rhs = std::move(temp); }`

Comment: somehow the misunderstanding is that you dont know how to avoid the branch, but others dont understand why you need a branch in the first place (in the code as posted). I suggest you to review your code and try to explain why you added a branch (maybe first to your rubber duck).

Comment: Branch operations are what makes a computer and computer and not a calculator.  You have been told some nonsense.  Every instruction requires instruction cycles and branching may affect pipelining and caching, but I would not sweat the small stuff in this instance.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Thanks for all the effort. I got it.

Comment: you are welcome, note that modifiying the code in the question after there are answers causes some friction and confusion. I know it is not simple to write a good question, but including a [mcve] right from the start is always better

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Sure I will keep that in mind. Thanks for the valuable feedback.

Comment: _"My question is can we avoid the if conditions?"_  Then that is what you should ask. In the question not hidden in a comment.

Comment: "since I was told that branch operations are costly in embedded programming" Generally low-end microcontrollers are far less picky with this than mid- to high-end ones. Depends on your target. Don't try to manually optimize code unless you have a (range of) intended targets for the code.

Comment: `int* pIn = pInputArr[i];` How does this make sense in the first place? Is this an array of pointers? If so that's a likely performance bottleneck in itself and you should start your optimization journey by not using strange pointer-based look-up tables or other such obscure data formats.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to check the evenness if you want to alternate – just swap.

```
for(int Input_number =0;Input_number<3;Input_number++)
{
    Some_fun(pIn, pOut);
    std::swap(pIn, pOut);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but not using the built in function swap.

Comment: @SauravRai the essence of this answer is not using `std::swap`, but rather to just remove the branch

Comment: @SauravRai If you don't want to use what the standard library has to offer, write your own. `template<class T> void myswap(T&a, T&b) { T tmp(a); a=b;  b=tmp; }`

Comment: @TedLyngmo `template<class T> void myswap(T&a, T&b) { T tmp(std::move(a)); a=b;  b=std::move(tmp); }` Which of course doesn't really matter when `T` is a pointer type, but it could matter when `T` is a non-pointer type.

Comment: @RemyLebeau True. I shouldn't even have made it a template for this case. Also, if `std::swap` isn't allowed I bet `std::move` isn't either.

Comment: @TedLyngmo well, `std::move()` is just a type-cast, which you can do manually, too: `T&& move(T& t) { return static_cast<T&&>(t); }  template<class T> void myswap(T&a, T&b) { T tmp(move(a)); a=b;  b=move(tmp); }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Indeed, but I think `void myswap(int* a, int* b) { int* tmp=a; a=b; b=tmp; }` would probably have had a bigger chance of being considered in this case.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I think you meant `void myswap(int* &a, int* &b)`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Indeed ... Too tired for this :-)

Answer (score 2):

What you need is more of a formula that takes the condition value and does something with it. In your scenario, you can create an array with `pInputArr[i]` and `pOutputArr[i]`, then use the condition value (0 or 1) to make the assignment. I would also prefer bitwise anding with 1 over modulo-checking since it is a single-operation expression:

```
int arr = {pInputArr[i], pOutputArr[i]};
bool cond = Input_number & 1;
pIn = arr[!cond];
pOut = arr[cond];
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to go brancheless you would do something like:

```
int isInputNumberOdd = Input_number % 2; 
pIn  = (pOutputArr[i] * isInputNumberOdd) + (pInputArr[i] * (1 - isInputNumberOdd));
pOut = (pOutputArr[i] * (1 - isInputNumberOdd)) + (pInputArr[i] * isInputNumberOdd);
```

You'll alway have one term of you addition multuplied by zero, effectivly setting the value to the other one.

Comment: Do note that this may very well be slower than a branch with all of the additional work being done (for non pointers).

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop `input_number` half the times and call the function twice instead.

```
for(int i = 0; i < Number; ++i) {     
     for(int Input_number = 0; Input_number < 100 / 2; ++Input_number) {
        Some_fun(pInputArr[i], pOutputArr[i]);
        Some_fun(pOutputArr[i], pInputArr[i]);
    }
}
```

or if your compiler isn't able to optimize the above to only do the subscripting in each array once:

```
int* pIn;
int* pOut;
for(int i = 0; i < Number; ++i) {     
     for(int Input_number = 0; Input_number < 100 / 2; ++Input_number) {
        pIn = pInputArr[i];
        pOut = pOutputArr[i];
        Some_fun(pIn, pOut);
        Some_fun(pOut, pIn);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No doubt your algorithm can be improved, but you are sweating the small stuff if you are worrying about branch instructions - let the compiler optimiser worry about that and concentrate of efficient algorithms over instruction-level optimisations.

For example you could simply "unroll" the loop:

```
for( int Input_number = 0;  Input_number < 100; Input_number += 2 )
{
    Some_fun(pIn,pOut );
    pIn = pOutputArr[i];
    pOut = pInputArr[i];
    
    Some_fun(pIn,pOut );
    pOut =  pOutputArr[i];
    pIn = pInputArr[i];
}
```

Then there is no test for odd/even and `if-else`.  You cannot eliminate branching in computing, the `for` loop involves branching as does the function call.  You can however have efficient algorithms with fewer branches, but more importantly eliminating unnecessary expression evaluation.

Further you can eliminate the assignments:

```
for( int Input_number = 0;  Input_number < 100; Input_number += 2 )
{
    Some_fun( pInputArr[i], pOutputArr[i] ) ;
    Some_fun( pOutputArr[i], pInputArr[i] ) ;
}
```

The point is there are two things to avoid in optimisation:

- Premature optimising - spending time making something faster that is already fast enough
- Micro-optimisation - worrying about how the compiler will translate your code to machine instructions and second-guessing it.

You have probably attempted both here.  What you should concentrate on is intrinsically efficient algorithms and data structures, and leave instruction generation to the compiler.

Comment: How is `Input_number | 1 == 0` equivalent to `Input_number % 2 == 0`? Did you mean to use `&`?

Comment: @WaisKamal Yes - brain burp, but it is academic in any case, the OP has retitled his question, so I am removing the now irellevant part.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a 2-element array to hold the pointers you want to swap, and then use the result of your calculation as an index into that array, eg:

```cpp
int** pArr[2];
int *pIn, *pOut;

for(int i = 0; i < Number; ++i)
{     
    pArr[0] = &pInputArr[i];
    pArr[1] = &pOutputArr[i];

    pIn = *pArr[0];
    pOut = *pArr[1];

    for(int Input_number = 0; Input_number < 100; ++Input_number)
    {
        Some_fun(pIn, pOut);
        bool isEven = (Input_number % 2 == 0);
        pIn = *pArr[isEven];
        pOut = *pArr[!isEven];
    }
}
```

Alternatively, since you know the result of the calculation will toggle on each loop iteration, then just get rid of the calculation altogether. eg:

```cpp
int** pArr[2];
int *pIn, *pOut;
bool isEven;

for(int i = 0; i < Number; ++i)
{     
    pArr[0] = &pInputArr[i];
    pArr[1] = &pOutputArr[i];

    pIn = *pArr[0];
    pOut = *pArr[1];

    isEven = true;

    for(int Input_number = 0; Input_number < 100; ++Input_number)
    {
        Some_fun(pIn, pOut);
        pIn = *pArr[isEven];
        pOut = *pArr[!isEven];
        isEven = !isEven;
    }
}
```

Note that in both examples above, I am using a pointer-to-pointer to determine each array element to pass to `Some_fun()`.  This is because your original code re-indexes into the `pInputArr[]` and `pOutputArr[]` arrays on each iteration, and it is not clear whether or not `Some_fun()` can change what those arrays are pointing at on each iteration.  If they don't change, then as [@molbdnilo suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66123380/65863), you can just swap the local pointers on each iteration instead, eg:

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < Number; ++i)
{     
    int *pIn = pInputArr[i];
    int *pOut = pOutputArr[i];

    for(int Input_number = 0; Input_number < 100; ++Input_number)
    {
        Some_fun(pIn, pOut);

        int *pTmp = pIn;
        pIn = pOut;
        pOut = pTmp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If your sure that you will be running 100 times, and that each `some_fun()` should alternate the arguments, you can ditch the if statements altogether,

```cpp
for(int Input_number = 0; Input_number < 50; Input_number++)
{
    Some_fun(pIn, pOut);
    Some_fun(pOut, pIn);
}
```

This way you don't need to swap the two or use if statements.

Comment: Are you suggesting me to use concepts such as ping pong buffers?. Correct me if I guess right?

Comment: @SauravRai If indexing one before the other doesn't effect the other, then why do you need to break them into two different branches? Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: FYI, some compilers can replace `% 2` with `& 2` at higher optimization levels.  It involves pattern recognition.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Oh I hope not, one tests the low bit, the other tests the second lowest bit.  Besides that easily fixed mistake, they also give different results on negative inputs.